# How to make boost multiprecision library work in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gcc, boost, mingw

I downloaded and installed Boost. It works but multiprecision part of library (especially float128.h) needs some external libs depends on libquadmath from gcc. I downloaded MinGW, installed and it still doesn't work. How to make it work?

Comment: What have you done further. what have you installed , mingw ? or other parts ? Have you told Visual-studio where to find `libquadmath-0.dll` is `C:\MinGW\bin` in the PATH variable ?

Comment: I installed minGW, set up PATH variable (C:\MinGW\bin) in My Computer->Settings.., set up includes in VS (C:\MinGW\include), set up C:\MinGW\lib in linker settings and receives 1>c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h(51): fatal error C1189: #error :  ERROR: You must use a GNU Compiler.

Comment: You can not include the whole `C:\MinGW\include` and `C:\MinGW\lib` they are not compatible with `VS` . You must include `#include <quadmath.h>` and the `libquadmath-0.dll` that's the parts you need not the complete mingw thing. [how other tries to use](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/oleg.davydov/tsfit/INSTALL) . May help .