# How to use boost::multiprecision::float128 in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I am trying to use boost::multiprecision::float128 in visual studio 2010. I found this link

[How to make boost multiprecision library work in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742589/how-to-make-boost-multiprecision-library-work-in-visual-studio-2010)

But still i am getting errors.

1>c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\quadmath.h(32): error C2144: syntax error : 'float' should be preceded by ';'

1>c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\quadmath.h(32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

What are the exact steps to be followed. A Complete step by step guide would be very helpful.

Comment: Apart the lack of any code (you should post an example) you speak about visual studio and then report an error that makes one think you are using mingw.

Comment: @marom: You didn't read the question Vincent linked to, did you?

Comment: This is, tbh, a duplicate of that question. Why repost?

Answer (score 2):

The float128 number type in Boost is a very thin wrapper around GCC's __float128 or Intel's _Quad data types.  This means that you would need GCC or Intel C++ compiler.  It does not work on Microsoft Visual C++.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this whole "pull in quadmath.h from GCC" thing is an unsupported hack, and it may that the previous guys simply got lucky with coincidentally-compatible versions.... and that you didn't. I would probably advise using another library that's officially supported in VS.

Comment: we are using only boost. Using other libraries is not allowed. I have also downloaded MINGW to C:\ drive. Below are the project settings.

C/C++ => General => Additional include Directories
C:\Boost_1_54_0

Linker => General => Additional Library Directories
C:\boost_1_54_0\lib
C:\MinGW\lib

Changes to the source file
#include "C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\quadmath.h"
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

Comment: @VincentAnthonySwamy: Not allowed by whom? Who is it that said "you may only use this one set of libraries, whether or not they are capable of achieving our goals"?

Comment: Just to limit additional libraries. But is there any way to use  boost::multiprecision::float128 in visual studio 2010.

Comment: @VincentAnthonySwamy: Is it supported?

Comment: Boost is supported  
  #include "boost/chrono/chrono.hpp"  works fine
  
.But #include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp> gives error

Comment: @VincentAnthonySwamy: That is not what I asked.

Comment: Just wanted to know any way to use boost::multiprecision::float128 in visual studio 2010. so it could be future compatible with new c++ standards.

Comment: @VincentAnthonySwamy: And I am asking you whether boost::multiprecision::float128 supports Visual Studio 2010. You will have to read the documentation to find that out. If yes, yes. If no, no.